# include custom code in wordpress for purge varnish

Tags: php, wordpress, varnish, purge

I should add custom code in the end functions.php (in theme directory) for wordpress website for Purges on a Post Publish or Purges on a Post Delete, Is there a way to include this code for all wordpress website without change functions.php file?  Sometimes some functions.php file is encrypted by IonCube and cannot be changed it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The question is why you would want to do this, provided that there are already plugins to do the job. E.g. [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/varnish-http-purge/).

Comment: I don't want users to have to install plug-ins. Automatically included without any change from the user side.